# Interpreting ACF and PACF plots on trading volume

Tags: time-series, interpretation, stationarity, finance, acf-pacf

I'm a fairly new one to time series analysis. I was analyzing the daily trading volume of stock derivatives for the past year and trying to see if there is a seasonality pattern. I tried to make the time series stationary by doing a log transformation and shifting it by 7 days. I chose lags value by referring to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140778/what-is-the-best-lag-length-for-auto-correlation). These are the plots I got after performing ACF and PACF, the plot on the bottom is the log-transformed volume shifted by one week.

[image]

However, I am confused by how should I interpret the results. Does it imply that there is a pattern occuring every 21 days? Or am I missing something while performing an analysis?

Comment: What do you mean by *shifting by 7 days*? It looks like this way you have introduced autocorrelation at lag 7, 14, 21, 35, 42, 56, 63, 70, 77 -- all multiples of 7.

Comment: I tried to make the series stationary, because my log-transformed series still wasn't stationary, so I used the following code: `log_diff = fv['log'].diff()[7:]`

Comment: Well, I am not sure what this code does, but it looks like it differences the series. Perhaps at lag 7, perhaps not.

Comment: Yes, it does difference the series because there was a seasonality appearing every week, so I tried removing it. However, even after differencing the weekly lag persists. Does that mean that I have a weekly cycle in my time series?

Comment: I guess it does, though I would only be confident differencing a series if it has a unit root. Otherwise you end up overdifferencing it (you may look up the keyword).